# func = Lambda x = something: x

Tags: python, lambda

I was doing some exercises on codewars and found this question:

> Complete the function `scramble(str1, str2)` that returns true if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise returns false.

after completing it and looking at others answers I found:

```
scramble=lambda a,b,c=__import__('collections').Counter:not c(b)-c(a)
```

Can someone explain what is happening here? Why is there a `=` after the declaration of lambda and how are the arguments being assigned???

I did not found much explanation on this.

Comment: Beside the point, but just in case you weren't aware, [avoid named lambdas](/q/38381556/4518341), use a `def` instead. I suppose this is one reason why :)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Just to note, It's against PEP8 and not readable at all but a cool syntax useful for mini scripts in those websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equal sign is setting a default value for the `c` argument. The default value is `__import__('collections').Counter`.

The lambda is equivalent to

```
def scramble(a, b, c=__import__('collections').Counter):
    return not c(b)-c(a)
```

or, extracting the import,

```
import collections
def scramble(a, b, c=collections.Counter):
    return not c(b)-c(a)
```

except that `__import__` doesn't assign the imported module to the `collections` variable.